# Record values of one column based on another column: Python & Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe

```
id value
a 1
b 1
a 1
c 1
d 2
a 1
g 2
....
```

I want to create an array of all the unique `id`'s if `value` equals `1`. In this case, an output of `['a', 'b', 'c']`. The dataframe is set up so there should be no overlap - `a` `b` and `c` only appear if the value equals `1`.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc` and a boolean mask to filter the dataframe and select the 'id' column, then call `unique()` to remove duplicates:

```
In [5]:

df.loc[df.value == 1,'id'].unique()
Out[5]:
array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)
```